# Lists of integers coprime to another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of integers. The first, `p`, is a list of primes (for example, `{2,3,5,7}`). The second is a list `t` of three arbitrary integers (positive, negative, or zero), for example `{10,15,24}`. You are guaranteed at the outset that each element of `t` is prime to at least one element of `p`. I want to produce a list `s` having the same length as `p`, where each element of `s` comes from `t` (repetitions allowed) and such that `CoprimeQ[s[[i]],p[[i]]]` is True for each `i`. So in the above example `{15,10,24,15}` and `{15,10,24,24}` would both be acceptable answers.

I can produce a matrix that expresses whether each element of `t` is prime to each element of `p` using

```
Table[CoprimeQ[i, p], {i, t}]
```

but I don't see how to proceed efficiently from there. Or perhaps there's a better way altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
p = {2, 3, 5, 7};
t = {10, 15, 24};
sol = Flatten[
  Table[RandomSample[Select[t, CoprimeQ[p[[i]], #] &], 1], {i, 1, 4}]];

CoprimeQ[p[[#]], sol[[#]]] & /@ Range[4]

(*{True, True, True, True}*)
```

Comment: Yes, I guess that's much easier than the complicated scheme I was cooking up. Thanks.